# CD AWS Amplify without Git Flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-codepipeline, cd

The AWS Amplify service allows for multiple branches to be configured within a single Amplify application and this is how CD is performed. Each stage is assigned to a particular branch and auto-builds when branch changes are pushed. From my understanding this is the Git Flow like approach, having different branches for each stage.

We have split up our Amplify app now however such that stages are separate Amplify applications; this was done as we are using the CDK and wish to have CD/CI deployment for Amplify infrastructure and components. The infrastructure is now CD using Code Pipelines and self-mutates. This all works using the "master" branch and so any pushes to this branch will push changes to the Code Pipeline, first deploying to our test stage and then to our production stage.

The trouble here is that we now have infrastructure being CD from "master" whereas the actual app that Amplify runs uses separate branches ("master" and "prod"). What I would like to happen is that whenever we push say the infrastructure change to production then it will also update the Amplify app with the "master" branch logic too.

I have looked into this and found a couple of solutions but neither of them are ideal:

1. Webhooks - The production App could be set to not be auto-built and a webhook triggered after infrastructure deployment to perform the update. This could work but does mean that the App will use the HEAD state of the master branch which may in theory be ahead of the infrastructure change should multiple commits be pushed at once. Given that our staged pipeline has a manual deploy step then the chance of this happening is high and not ideal.
2. Custom lambda to run `aws amplify start-job commit-id=xyz`; after a deployment we run this command with the commit-id of the CodePipeline execution. This will allow us to get the exact change but is extra overhead and infrastructure to maintain. We will also need to do this cross-account.

Is there a solution I am overlooking? Is there a way to align our infrastructure as code and our app code to deploy at the same time at the same commit entry without the need for separate branches?

Comment: Why don't you just switch environment locally?

Comment: @Arturo how do you mean by switch locally?

Comment: Something like: `amplify env checkout dev` or `amplify env checkout prod` to switch between Amplify environments